# Usage multiple view of same component with same reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I have created a view with store because have some header list components. In timeline we want to show 2 of this. Like belove. So should i remove the reducer dependency? What would your solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should not write a Redux reducer "for a view" in the first place. Redux is your data layer. It should not contain your data in a format that is especially readable for a certain component, but it should contain the data for your application - and each component can use selectors to get the data out of it that it needs.
Having one reducer that exactly has the right shape and data for a component/view is essentially an antipattern. It should not have a lot of influence on the shape or contents of your Redux store if you have one view, two views, or five views displaying that data.

I highly recommend you read the [Redux Style Guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/) as I guess you might have a few other ideas that might be going against our recommendations.

Also, as you are using the word "reducer", and not the more modern "slice", you *might* be using an outdated style of Redux. Just to make sure you are aware of this: modern Redux does not use `switch..case` reducers, ACTION_TYPES, immutable reducer update logic, `connect`/`mapStateToProps` and `createStore`/`applyMiddleware` any more. Modern Redux is about 1/4 of the code and avoids common pitfalls. [You can read about it here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).

If you need a tutorial that shows modern Redux and explains how it should be used, I would recommend you to look at [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Comment: Thanks phry can you explain this for example in "the view" and "view 2" i am using 2 different visualize type preview and list view. If i am store this data in slice 2 of them change same time. List and header different components. Should i use react contex for reach the data in different components?

Comment: How about this. I think i need a component based slice. Not the entire store?

Comment: You need different slices for different type of data, or features. Your components would each use selectors to access parts of that. Also, there is no concept of a "view" in React at all. Tbh., you are using a lot of words here that don't have a meaning in the context of React and Redux and are not really explaining anything you do with code, so it's hard to give you concrete feedback. I'd really recommend you to go with the tutorials to get a feeling on how this should be used.

Comment: I think the first comment(question) of this main comment so clear. Maybe i should set an array to initial state but it is unusual i think. I am really confused about that. I am using same data type just a type difference in entity like left side of the view(component) show me first month of  entries and the second part show second months record but it is not also data components have other specific values like list or preview mode.

Comment: Your question says you created a view with a store. In React, Views don't exist. In Redux, you only create one store for your whole application, never for a component. I have no idea what you mean with a reducer dependency (and if that were a term people use, I'd know, I'm a Redux maintainer). I'm sorry, but it is not clear at all. Please add more details, and source code to your question. Also, an array as initial state could mean pretty much everything without code showing what you mean by that.

Comment: So, please, don't ask four sentences and a sketch. Provide source code and point out what your problem with the source code is.